# Load target ajax php file on initial page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onload

I have an AJAX setup in php to return and dispaly some data from DB:

```
$("#sub_shops").click(function(){
                    var range_start = $("#start_shops").val();
                    var range_end = $("#end_shops").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'process_shops.php',
                        data:{start:range_start,end:range_end},
                        type:'POST',
                        success:function(data){
                            $("#result_shops").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

There are two inputs on page `#start_shops` and `#end_shops`, after filling in data and clicking `#sub_shops` page sends values from inputs to `process_shops.php`. After processing, it displays the results in `#result_shops`:

```
<div id="result_shops"></div>
```

The question:

If there are default values are set for `#start_shops` and `#end_shops` inputs, how do I send it's values to `process_shops.php` and display processed results in `#result_shops` on **initial page load**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: rather than using `page load` wait for `DOMContentLoaded` so the DOM elements are available - at which point you should be able to get their values using either vanilla javascript of jQuery ( or other )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First break your code out into a function:

```
function updateResultShops()
{
    var range_start = $("#start_shops").val();
    var range_end = $("#end_shops").val();
    $.ajax({
       ...
}
```

Then call it from the click handler:

```
$("#sub_shops").click(updateResultShops);
```

And on document load!

```
$(document).ready(updateResultShops);
```

Now any initial values will be sent immediately when the page loads, and every time you click. Easy!

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If the values are pre-loaded in the inputs, I think the easiest way would be

```
$("#sub_shops").click(function(){
    // your code...
}).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could turn the anonymous function into a function.

```js
function loadAjax()
{
   /* Commented this part since it wont run on the snippet.

   var range_start = $("#start_shops").val();
   var range_end = $("#end_shops").val();
   $.ajax({
     url:'process_shops.php',
     data:{start:range_start,end:range_end},
     type:'POST',
     success:function(data){
       $("#result_shops").html(data);
     }
   });
   
   */

  alert("blablabla");
}

$("#sub_shops").click(loadAjax); //Add event to click
$(document).ready(loadAjax); //Add event to run when page loads.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: black; height: 50px; width: 50px;" id="sub_shops"></div>
```

But if you wish to leave the function inside the click... you can do this:

```
$(document).ready($("#sub_shops").click);
```